# How to implement n times repeated k-folds cross validation that yields n*k folds in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I got some trouble in implementing a cross validation setting that i saw in a paper. Basically it is explained in this attached picture:
[image]

So, it says that they use 5 folds, which means `k = 5`. But then, the authors said that they repeat the cross validation 20 times, which created 100 folds in total. Does that mean that i can just use this piece of code :

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=100, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
```

Cause basically my code also yields 100-folds. Any recommendation?

Comment: Yes.You can use this. This code snippet will have the same effect as the answer by @Abhishek Thakur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they are talking about `RepeatedStratifiedKFold`. You have 2 simple ways to create 5-folds for 20 times.

**Method 1:**

For your case, `n_splits=5, n_repeats=20`. Code below is just sample from scikit-learn website.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])

rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=2,
...     random_state=42)
>>> for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(X, y):
...     print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
...
TRAIN: [1 2] TEST: [0 3] # n_repeats==1: the folds are [1 2] and [0 3]
TRAIN: [0 3] TEST: [1 2]
TRAIN: [1 3] TEST: [0 2] # n_repeats==2: the folds are [1 3] and [0 2]
TRAIN: [0 2] TEST: [1 3]
```

**Method 2:**

> You can achieve the same effect with looping. Note that the `random_state` cannot be a fixed number, otherwise you will get the same 5 folds for 20 times.
>
> ```
> for i in range(20):
>     kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
> ```

***Why is it different from your code?***

Say you have 10000 data points and you create 100 folds. Size of 1 fold = 100. Your training set=9900 versus validation set=100.

`RepeatedStratifiedKFold` creates 5 folds for your model, each fold is 2000. Then it repeats making a 5 folds again, and again, for 20 times. That means that you achieve 100 folds, but have a much large validation set. Depending on your objective, you might want a larger validation set, eg. to have enough data to properly validate, and `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` gives you that ability to create the same number of folds in a different way (with different training-validation proportion). *Other than that, I'm not sure if there's any other objectives.*

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html

Thank you `RepeatedStratifiedKFold`.

Comment: @jasinlcy91 - For repeatedKFold cross validation, we don't need to do usual random train and test split? If we use the full input data `X` as input to the model, wouldn't that be a data leakage? For ex: Let's say I have data from 2017 to 2022. If I do repeataedKfold, as pass the input X, it is very much possible that model will use 2021 data points in train and use 2020 in test. So, isn't this incorrect?

Comment: Here is the related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724086/how-to-do-repeatedkfold-cv-the-right-way

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
for i in range(100):
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
```

Comment: do you mean `for i in range(20):` ? But what will it do? isn't it will only reassign the kfold variable again and again?

Comment: @AryoPradiptaGema yes it will. You need to implement your remaining code in that for loop using the k fold. The `random_state` will make sure that most of the times you will get different splits of data.

Comment: i'm having another trouble, i got `bad_alloc` error. Any idea how to free some memory after some iteration?

Comment: can you please post the full error? maybe open a new question?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - upvoted for useful answer..For repeatedKFold cross validation, we don't need to do usual random train and test split? If we use the full input data X as input to the model, wouldn't that be a data leakage? For ex: Let's say I have data from 2017 to 2022. If I do repeataedKfold, as pass the input X, it is very much possible that model will use 2021 data points in train and use 2020 in test. So, isn't this incorrect? Or should we do repeatedKfold only on `X_train` and later evaluate our model on `X_test`?

Comment: In addition to above comment, I would like to let you know that my dataset is small. 977 records only. So, if I pass full dataset `X`, I understand that model has large number of data points to validate the model..but isn't this a data leakage? Meaning, my input variables are all highly cardinal and if I have to do categorical encoding, I compute them based on list of categories encountered in full dataset.. I have to do encoding first to pass them to repeatedstratified k fold.

Comment: So, do you think it is okay to pass full dataset ( `X` and `y`) as input to the repeatedstratified k fold or should I only pass `X_train` and `y_train` as input?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - Here is the related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724086/how-to-do-repeatedkfold-cv-the-right-way