# How do I know that RepeatedStratifiedKFold is actually working as it should?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to choose a method to split my data into train and test sets. I am currently using Scikit's `RepeatedStratifiedKFold`. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html), the `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` is a:

> Repeated Stratified K-Fold cross validator.
>
> Repeats Stratified K-Fold `n` times with different randomization in each
> repetition.

I use the `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` using 5 folds and 100 repetitions on a dataset consisting of 1000 observations as follows:

```
rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=100, random_state=None)

for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(X, y):

   X_train, _X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]

   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

However, when I look at the `X_train` set, I only see 800 observations (4 train folds). Shouldn't it contain all 100 train sets as per the number of repetitions?

My second question: after splitting your data using the `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` method, what happens when you fit your classification model on the `X_train` and `y_train` datasets? Does the model train on all 100 repetitions?

Suppose I just wanted the F1-score from the model after testing it. Does it give me the average score across all 100 repetitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I look at the `X_train` set, I only see 800 observations (4 train folds). Shouldn't it contain all 100 train sets as per the number of repetitions?

Not really. Actually, when you loop through `rksf.split(X, y)`, you are looping through the number of iterations (given by `n_splits * n_repeats`). In this case, you are looping through 5 * 100 = 500 iterations - each of them with different partitions. You can very easily check this by adding a counter to your loop and printing it:

```
ii = 1
for train_index, test_index in rskf.split(X, y):
   print(f"Iteration {ii}")

   X_train, _X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

   ii += 1
```

Which would result in

```
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
...
Iteration 499
Iteration 500
```

Thus, it makes sense that when you run your code you see that `X_train` has 800 observations. That corresponds to the partition of *one* of your iterations. If this isn't clear yet, I suggest you take a look at this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030937/948768).

---

> My second question: after splitting your data using the `RepeatedStratifiedKFold` method, what happens when you fit your classification model on the `X_train` and `y_train` datasets? Does the model train on all 100 repetitions?

No, the way you have it currently defined, the model would be fitted using `X_train` and `y_train` of a *single* iteration.

---

> Suppose I just wanted the F1-score from the model after testing it. Does it give me the average score across all 100 repetitions?

No, related to your earlier question, you would get the F1-score of a single iteration. You could save the F1-score of each iteration in a list and then get calculate the average (and maybe also SD). You could also consider using Scikit's [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score)