# How to do repeatedKfold CV the right way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, cross-validation

I am working on a binary classification using random forest with a dataset size of 977 records and 6 columns. class ratio is 77:23 (imbalanced dataset)

Since, my dataset is small, I learnt that it is not advisable to split using regular train_test split of 70 and 30.

So, I was thinking to do repeatedKfold CV. Please find my code below

**Approach 1 - Full data - X, y**

```
rf_boruta = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=3,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=100)
scores = cross_val_score(rf_boruta,X,y, scoring='f1', cv=cv)
print('mean f1: %.3f' % mean(scores))
```

But I see that we have full input data `X` passed at once to the model. Doesn't this lead to data leakage? Meaning, if I am doing categorical encoding, we have to do based on all categories encountered in full dataset. Similarly, consider if a dataset ranges from the year 2017 to 2022. It is possible that model uses 2021 data in one of the folds and validate it on the 2020 data.

So, is it right to use `repeatedKfold` like the below?

**Approach 2 - only train data - X_train, y_train**

```
rf_boruta = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=3,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=100)
scores = cross_val_score(rf_boruta,X_train,y_train, scoring='f1', cv=cv)
print('mean f1: %.3f' % mean(scores))
```

Can help me understand which will be the best approach to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that there are two ways to do it. The first way is to write the code for training and validating manually. Here is an example of a code for it:

```py
scores = []
folds = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=100)
for fold_n, (train_index, valid_index) in enumerate(folds.split(train, y, groups=train['breath_id'])):
    X_train, X_valid = X[columns].iloc[train_index], X[columns].iloc[valid_index]
    y_train, y_valid = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[valid_index]
    
    encoder = LabelEncoder()
    encoder.fit(X_train[:, 0])
    X_train[:, 0] = encoder.transform(X_train[:, 0])
    X_valid [:, 0] = encoder.transform(X_valid [:, 0])
    rf_boruta = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced',max_depth=3,max_features='sqrt',n_estimators=300)

    rf_boruta .fit(X_train, y_train)
    score = metrics.f1_score(y_valid, rf_boruta .predict(X_valid))
    
    scores.append(score)
```

The second way is to use Pipeline from sklearn:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# creating artificial data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=6, n_informative=4, n_redundant=2)
# making one of the column categorical
X[:, 0] = np.random.randint(0, 10, 1000)
# converting into DataFrame so that we can use column names
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = [str(i) for i in range(6)])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', StandardScaler(), ['1', '2']),
        ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), ['0']),
    ]
)                                  
                                  
rf = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced', max_depth=3, max_features='sqrt', n_estimators=300)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=10)
pipe = Pipeline([('transformer', preprocessor), ('rf', rf)])
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, scoring='f1', cv=cv)
print(f'Mean f1: {np.mean(scores):.3f}')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, upvoted, but one quick question. Don't you think passing `X` as input to RepeatedKfoldCV leads to data leakage? Why not just X_train?

Comment: When you use a pipeline, for each fold X and y are split into train and validation set, transformers are fit only on train part of the data.

Comment: So, now how do you get the `validation` data from that pipeline?

Comment: In 1st approach, I see that we are able to get the validation data through the for loop iterations etc. But how do I get the validation data from pipeline?

Comment: If you need to get validation data on each step, then you need to use the first approach. If you need only validation scores, then the second approach may be enough.

Comment: Okay, one data science question. So, if we use 2nd approach, you make use of the complete dataset. So, to evaluate your model, you will have go for another new dataset? Am I right?

Comment: Both approaches work similarly: in both cases, X and y are split into train and valid; at each step, transformers and models are fit only on the train and then used on the validation data. If all random seeds are defined, the results should be the same. The difference is that in the first approach, you can keep all the data, models, and transformers from each fold.
But additionally, you may be interested in calculating the metrics on a separate holdout dataset - in this case; only the first approach will work.

Comment: Let's say in data poor settings, I can pass X_train as main input to the Kfold and create valid sets out of that. Right? And I can use my remaining X_test as test dataset (instead if going for additional new dataset). Is this a right way to go about when we have poor data?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.

Comment: If you have time, can I seek your views on this post? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569423/how-to-not-overfit-with-little-data

Comment: This is a difficult situation. I agree that it is better to use class_weights instead of oversampling. First suggestion: check your features again - maybe some of them have too high variance and thus cause the difference between train and validation metrics. Second suggestion: in my first approach we can train N models on each fold... and then make an ensemble on them - make predictions with each model and average the predicitons; usually this leads to better and more stable results.

Comment: but don't you think for my dataset of size 977 records, such huge ensembles are required? I tried bootstrapping. You can find them here . You can leave your answer her if you have time https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570172/bootstrap-optimism-corrected-results-interpretation

Comment: Ensembles usually help. But it is difficult to give a specific example without looking at the data itself.